# Post-apocalyptic movie from early 1970's - people turn into powder

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I've got another movie from my childhood that I'm trying to find.

I saw it on TV (in the US) no later than 1975-76, in English.

The plot was an ongoing end-of-civilization event. There was a small group of people in the woods trying to survive. People would fall asleep in their sleeping bags and the next day the others would find that the person had turned into some white powder. Not ash, looked more like salt. I was very young when I saw it so can't remember much else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [Where Have All the People Gone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072400/combined) with Peter Graves from 1974:

> A strange series of solar flares proves fatal for inhabitants of the Earth, except for the fortunate few who are somehow immune from the effects. Animals go insane and **human beings turn to white powder, leaving behind only empty clothing.** A handful of survivors attempt to rebuild their lives on the de-populated Earth.

The entire film is currently available on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IK0BpOa2vk) and around 16:35 you can see the white powder being found in a sleeping bag.